# PHP cURL timeout being ignored?

Tags: php, apache, curl, timeout

I have a node server listening on server1 and a PHP script that curls the node server from server2. This triggers a script. The problem I'm having is that I get "The connection has timed out, The server XXXXXX is taking too long to respond". The script takes a while to run as it is deploying a new server on AWS and I'm waiting for the output log from that script to be returned from the cURL request.

I have changed the Timeout setting in my apache2.conf to 6000 (100 minutes) and restarted apache2.

Options I have in my PHP code:

```
set_time_limit(0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
```

Am I missing something? I've Googled around but I can't find any other settings that I should set. I've seen the CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT option but there is no problem connecting as I can see the output from the script on the actual server.

Comment: Timed it, It seems to be timing out after 5 minutes which would be 300 seconds. That's the timeout set in apache but I have set that to 6000. Where else could this be being set?

Comment: I have also now added CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0) but It's still timing out.

Comment: To be clear you raised the timeout on the destination server - the server you are calling to not the server you are calling from?  Also, the script you are calling?  Is it also PHP and what are the timeouts on the server with regards to php.

Comment: If I curl server1 from the terminal, it doesn't time out. Only when the PHP on server2 curls it.

Comment: So you server2 you are using PHP to curl an object from server 1?

Comment: What happens if you use curl directly from server 2 to server 1?

Comment: Curling from the command line works fine, no timeout. Server 2 uses PHP cURL to trigger a script on server1 and waits for the response. The response is the output from the script but the script takes a long time and the page times out before it completes. I need it to wait indefinitely for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem!

It's the firefox built in timeout.

I went to `about:config` and set `network.http.response.timeout` to `3000`

This solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

On server sending the curl request, check the php.ini file - as it sounds like the max script time in PHP is timing out.